# Array can't pass to blade. What should I do?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to pass an Array to blade template.
but somehow the array always become null in blade.
I don't where I should fix.

```
    public function stackover(Request $request)
    {
        $resultList = array();
        $dateListArray = $this->getChargeData($request->id);
        Log::debug($dateListArray);
        foreach($dateListArray as $datelist)
        {
            array_push($resultList,$datelist);
        }
        Log::debug("CHARGELIST");
        Log::debug($resultList);
        return view('stacker',compact($resultList));
    }
```

in blade.php

```
  console.log({{$resultList ?? ''}});
```

data becomes empty.

```
Log::debug("CHARGELIST");
Log::debug($chargeList);
```

The result is here

```
 array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'delivery_date' => '2021-08-03 00:00:00',
     'amount' => 10000,
     'cost' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'delivery_date' => '2021-08-06 00:00:00',
     'amount' => 400,
     'shipping_cost' => 1100,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'delivery_date' => '2021-08-13 00:00:00',
     'amount' => 1100,
     'cost' => 1100,
  ),
)
```

Comment: `{{}}` is for outputting scalar types not compound types. If you want to use an array, you can do `console.log(@json($resultList))`

Comment: To test for php value, use `dd($resultList)`, dont rely on JS as some conversion error rmight happen.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to the fact that your are passing the `$resultList` variable as value to the `compact` function instead of the name of the variable as a string`

```
return view('stacker',compact($resultList));
```

You should fix that by changing the above line like this

```
return view('stacker',compact('resultList'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have alternates to get the array in the blade.

```
return View::make('stacker',$resultList);
```

The compact() function is used to convert a given variable to an array in which the key of the array will be the name of the variable and the value of the array will be the value of the variable.

```
return view('stacker',compact('resultList'));
```

If you already have the array you can pass it with the with() function.

```
 return view('stacker')->with($resultList);
```